# Operating on summarized values in a matrixed report

Tags: reporting, custom-object, relationships, schema-builder

Hello fellow Trailblazers

I'm in a bit of a pickle here

I have two tables referring to buys of gas and gas sales to customers. Each table has the same fields (date, price/liter and quantity in liters)

The goal is to create a report where I can show the Total quantity bought per month (liters), Total quantity sold per month (liters); total bought per month (currency), total sold per month (currency); Average price/liter per month (bought), Average price/liter per month (sold); and profit margin per month (avg price/liter (sold) minus avg price/liter (bought).

I tried to include all the fields [date (bought and sold), price/liter (bought and sold) and quantity in liters(bought and sold)] in the same object (transaction) and I added a checkbox field with the type of transaction (buy or Sale) and a formula field that calculates the total amount(currency) of that transaction.

Then I created a matrix report that looks like this:
[image]

So now I have almost the required data but I can't find a way to obtain the profit margin, i.e., how can I calculate avg monthly price/liter sold minus avg monthly price/liter bought in the report.

I tried another way: I created two objects (Gas Buys and Gas Sales) each with date, price/liter and quantity(liters) and a formula field that calculates the total amount (currency) of the transaction (record).

So now my problem is in the reporting because i cannot find a way to relate these two objects

Comment: Hi @identigral, thanks for the answer, I had already checked the summary formula column but it only does Sum, Min, Max, Avg and Median. Also I couldn't compose a formula since the values of the price/liter field in the object are not averages it's the price of the gas in the date of the record. The Row-level formula contains the fields of the object but what my report shows (see image) as the average price per liter is the average that the report calculated. I wonder if I could use those values somehow. Even so I'll check the project that you mencioned.

Comment: Row-level and/or summary formula on the report; https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/rd-summary-formulas and https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000394930&type=1